# How to prevent the page from reloading or refreshing on cancel option?

Tags: javascript, forms, submit, confirm, onsubmit

I am trying to prevent the page from reloading or submitting when the user clicks the Cancel option. I looked around stackoverflow and have the same syntax for the problem I'm having, but I tried something like this and it still submits and reload the page on cancel option. How do I prevent it from doing anything and leave the page as-is on cancel?

**JavaScript code:**

```
// create an input element
var frm = document.getElementById("result");
var submitBtn = document.createElement("input");
submitBtn.type = "submit";
submitBtn.value = "Confirm Purchase";
frm.appendChild(submitBtn);
submitBtn.addEventListener('click', function()
{
    // confirm the data
    var submitQ = confirm('Are you sure you want to submit your DSLR selections?');
    if(submitQ)
    {
    alert('Your query has been submitted! Have a great day! :)');
    }
    else document.getElementById("result").onsubmit = false; // prevent the page from refreshing on Cancel option
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<form id="result" onsubmit="true">
    <!--Store User Selection Text Node Element Here-->
        <!--<p>Your DSLR budget range selected was:</p>
    <p>The DSLR brand you selected was:</p>
    <p>The type of photography you selected was:</p>
    <p>The type of lenses you selected was:</p>
    <input type="submit" value="Confirm Purchase"/>
    <input type="button" value="Reset All"/>-->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your event handler to address the form `onsubmit` event rather than the submit buttons `click` event. And return false if the user cancels :

```
frm.onsubmit = function(){
    // confirm the data
    var submitQ = confirm('Are you sure you want to submit your DSLR selections?');
    if(submitQ)
    {
    alert('Your query has been submitted! Have a great day! :)');
    } else {
       // prevent the page from refreshing on Cancel option
       return false;
    }
};
```

see fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/LGd2f/**

Comment: Are you sure? You do not seem to use the onsubmit handler in the loooong fiddle :) Here is an update where you can see for yourself if the page is reloaded or not -> http://jsfiddle.net/BS55A/

Comment: Thanks, finally got it! it seems `submitBtn.addEventListener` doesn't recognize the event because it's a button, nothing more. As oppose to using `frm.onsubmit` and use that value inside the event which the form has onsubmit. Thanks I'll keep this in mind!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should try attaching the event to form submit event instead of on a button click, and then just **return false** or **return true**.